# How to use my own node module

Tags: node.js, npm

I created a node module and can't seem to use it properly. Here's my index.js for said module:

```
const thing = require('./thing.js');
exports.thing = thing;
```

Here's thing.js:

```
module.exports = 'foobar';
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "thing-both",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here's the package.json in my other module that I want to use it in:

```
{
  "name": "another-thing",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "thing-both": "file:../both"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I run npm install and the module installs. When I try to require the module that I made in `anotherThing` module, I get the 'Cannot find module' error. This is my require statement:

```
const thing = require('thing-both');
```

One thing I noticed is that the installed module has no files and the folder has an icon in my directory sidebar (using Sublime 3 and the icon looks like a symlink icon):

[image]

Here's the project directory I'm working with:

```
both
  thing.js
  index.js
  package.json
other
  // stuff
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) in your library module, then use `npm link MODULE_NAME` in your consuming module.  You're getting this error because your library module is probably not hosted on the npm registry which is where `npm install` looks for modules.

This is a way to do rapid local development without having to commit your library module all the way up to the npm registry every time you make a change and want to test locally.

Comment: Gave it a try but still ran into the same error as before. I ran `npm link` in my  module directory `both`, then ran `npm link thing-both` in my module directory `other`. It looks like the link was setup correctly as my terminal was saying this was the case. Perhaps I'm not actually creating the node module correctly?

Comment: @skwny Look in the `node_modules` folder of the consumer module (I think it's "another-thing").  Is there a directory (or symlink) to the library module (I think you're calling it "thing-both")?  If there is, you need to be requiring the library in your JS with `var thingBoth = require("thing-both");`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case. I have a directory in the calling module's node_modules folder (which appears to have a symlink as an icon) and in my calling module I require it, although it is via `const thingBoth = require('thing-both')`. But note that when I expand the directory `thing-both` in the calling module's node_modules folder, nothing displays as shown in the original question.